# how to add license text to cx_freeze bdist_msi?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have a small python application and i want to add GNU GPL license text to MSI package, which cx_Freeze produces.

I use this setup scrip, with bdist_msi option:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

path = sys.path + ["app"]
build_exe_options = {
"path": path,
"icon": "resources\icons\clock.ico"}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "app",
        version = "1.1",
        description = "My Application",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("app.py", base=base,
            targetName="app.exe",
            shortcutName="Application",
            shortcutDir="DesktopFolder")])
```

How can i do that?

Comment: cx_Freeze's bdist_msi command is based on distutils' bdist_msi, which is based on msilib (something I never knew was in the standard library). It [looks like](http://docs.python.org/2/library/msilib.html#gui-classes) there are ways to modify the installer UI, but I guess you need to know about the structure of MSI packages to actually do that. Felix's suggestion of using another installer creator is much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html), cx_Freeze is able to build a *simple* installer which probably doesn't include showing a license (or at least I couldn't find it in the docs).
However, you can run your setup script with `python setup.py build` and then package the files up using a professional installer like [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) or [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). Both of them are free and let you customize pretty much everything you want, including showing a license.