# msi created by cx_freeze to select option from the given user interface(like licence agreement)

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I Want my msi created by cx_freeze to select options from the given list with a user interface (As it is in licence agreement).

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add license text to cx\_freeze bdist\_msi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766473/how-to-add-license-text-to-cx-freeze-bdist-msi)

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to use IExpress you can definitely put a licence with it.

If you run Windows it's definitely worth a go since it's installed by default.

Otherwise you could always build an exe create a GUI with it, all the options and then launch the msi afterwards.  For different options you could have a different msi.